# mybatis spring batch +sybase: trying to get the database identity value after insertion to assign it to the id field in pojo

Tags: sap-ase, spring-mybatis

my code looks like the sample code given below.

--table create statement

```
CREATE TABLE LOG
(
  uniqueID            NUMERIC(20,0) IDENTITY,
  NAME          VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  USR           VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
)
```

--pojo class

```
public class Log
{
  private long identifier;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String user;
  //getters+setters......
}
```

--insert statement in mapper

```
<insert id="insertRecord" parameterType="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.model.Log" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="identifier" keyColumn="uniqueID">
  INSERT INTO LOG (NAME, DESCRIPTION, USR)
  VALUES (#{log.name}, #{log.description}, #{log.user})
</insert>
```

**issue:** when i try to run this code against sybase database, am getting NullPointerException. When i tried to debug it, error came from within SybStatement.class. Sorry am not able to provide entier stacktrace due to constraint in copy/paste at my work station.

I am able to run the same code against H2 database successfully. Records got inserted and "identifier" in Log object is having the identify value same as database rows.

Did you face this issue in sybase?. Please share if anyone is having code for showing the usage of "useGeneratedKeys" mybatis feature in sybase..

**Note:**
I am running this insert statement using MybatisBatchItemWriter. 
I tried to use two different sqlsessiontemplate objects for chunk reader & chunk writer and it didn't resolve the issue.
I am using jconn3 sybase jdbc jar, mybatis 3.4.4 and mybatis-spring 1.3.1 jar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In SQL terms, you need to do SELECT @@IDENTITY to pick up the generated value. Thecquestion is if your framework generates such SQL...